# ionic add tabs to page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to add tabs to a page in Ionic.

It seems like a trivial task but for some reason they are not showing.

I have tried two ways;

One is Adding `/pages/tabs` and a `tabs.html` / `tabs.ts` file

tabs.html page.

```
<ion-tabs>
   <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab> 
   <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="information-circle">
   </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

tabs.ts page

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
   import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

   @Component({
     templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
   })
   export class TabsPage {

      tab1Root = HomePage;
      tab2Root = AboutPage;

     constructor() {
     }
    }
```

Then adding the tabs part into my app.module.ts page in 'declarations' and 'entryComponents'.

Second one is I tried adding the tabs html into the view for home...

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-tabs>
<ion-tab (click)="nav.setRoot(pages2.homePage)" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab (click)="nav.setRoot(pages2.aboutPage)" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
</ion-content>
```

In both implementations I get no tab bar showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the thing you are missing here is root property of the ion-tab. You can try like shown below.

```
<ion-tabs>
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" (ionSelect)="nav.setRoot(pages2.homePage)" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
<ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" (ionSelect)="nav.setRoot(pages2.aboutPage)" tabTitle="About" tabIcon="information-circle"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Using that code gives me 'Cannot read property 'setRoot' of undefined'

Comment: It seems issue is with something else. It is related to the click action defined in ionSelect. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve in click action. Can you try removing ionSelect and see whether tabs are showing..

Comment: I would just like to naviagate to the 'homePage' and 'aboutPage'

Comment: Did you try removing the (ionSelect)="nav.setRoot(pages2.homePage)" from both the tabs? It should work fine without it..

Comment: I have the exact same issue, did you  get it resolved?